# how to upload using facebook iphone api to post image and text from iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

Hope you all doing well, i have a one problem i want upload a small image with some text in front of that image from iphone, but not succeeded yet. I gone through some  blogs and post but not find any thing like that . Please suggest me some piece of sample code how to do that..
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FacebookConnect for iPhone](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk). There's a library and demo code.